# apache with a php-fpm instance on different machine

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

I'm setting up Apache with proxy_fcgid to pass the php-requests to a dedicated php-fpm instance on a remote machine.

Configuration on the Apache-Box:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
#  SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php56-fpm/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://xyz:9005#"
</FilesMatch>
<Proxy fcgi://localhost>
ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" PATH_INFO "%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
ProxySet connectiontimeout=5 timeout=240
</Proxy>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) - [H=text/html]
```

php-fpm.conf's settings are basically left to default, yet all requests 404 on the machine running php-fpm and

> ProxyPass fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/default/wwwroot/$1

also requires the full path on the local filesystem, leaving me clueless on how to run the scripts residing on the Apache-Box.

Comment: what is "proxy:fcgi://xyz:9005#" with # at the end?

Comment: If this is still of interest: You do not send the code over to the FPM machine, so you have to deploy the code there to.
It has to be in the same directory as it is on the host.